# Is there a way to make my USB-C headphones work?

Tags: 18.04, usb, headphones

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, faced with an issue: when I connect headphones through a Type-C dongle, the system doesn't see it. Both port and headphones are working, but the headphones aren't seen by OS. Is there a way to fix it? When connected, they don't even appear in audio settings, so I'm a bit out of ideas.

Comment: Watch `journalctl --follow` as you connect the headphones, and as you connect the dongle.

Comment: Hi were you able to figure out a solution to this? I am stuck in a similar situation too unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I am on Kubuntu 18.04 and connected a monitor (lg-27MU88-W) over USB-C. The monitor contains a headphone jack that appears as HDMI output in Audio preferences.

Selecting [Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyOCo.png) makes headphones work for me.